# How to hide items from a Community (hierarchically)?

Tags: content-management-system, user-experience, dspace

i know that's possible hide collections and collection items in JSPUI, by each collection or item, but exists some way to hide an Community or just items of this community like subcommunities / collections / items hierarchically, modifying just a Community ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the collections or items within a community from search, you will need to restrict the permissions on each of those items/collections.

To hide a community in XMLUI, you can suppress a community from the community list.

```
<xsl:template match="dri:referenceSet/dri:reference[contains(@url,'xxxxxx/yyyyyy')]" mode="community-browser"/>
```

In XMLUI, there is a wildcard tool to force permission updates to all descendants of a community.

Comment: We used XMLUI but as interface customizations and features were getting more complex we had to migrate to JSPUI for easier maintenance.

Is it possible to perform this procedure in JSPUI?

Comment: I do not use JSPUI, so I do not know how to make such a change.

Comment: In urgency, the best solution is to deploy the xmlui module internally to admin users.